# Передача в новое Activity ссылку на изображение

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на список, перенести ссылку на изображение
Код при передачи, текст передается, изображение нет! Не понимаю как составить ссылку, для передачи изображения.
Пробвал логировать, получается вот что:

```
    09-22 17:31:26.783 8609-8609/com.example.recipes I/images: imageResource:androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView{23be8596 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f070088 app:id/imageViewA}, text: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{2cd6c517 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #7f0700ed app:id/textViewTitle}
```

Код первого активити:

```
        public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        RecyclerViewItem recyclerViewItem = arrayList.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Recipes_activity.class);

        intent.putExtra("imageResource", recyclerViewItem.getImageResource());
        intent.putExtra("textName", recyclerViewItem.getTextName());
        intent.putExtra("textDescription", recyclerViewItem.getTextDescription());
        intent.putExtra("textInstruction", recyclerViewItem.getTextInstruction());
        context.startActivity(intent);

    }
```

Активити которое принимает данные:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes_activity);

    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewA);
    TextView  textName = findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    TextView textInstruction = findViewById(R.id.textViewInfo);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        //imageView.setImageURI(URI.parse);

        textName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("textName"));
        Log.i("images", "imageResource:" + imageView + ", text: " + textName);
        imageView.setImageURI((Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra("imageResource"));
        textInstruction.setText(intent.getStringExtra("textInstruction"));
    }

}
```

Comment: А что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Не переносится изображение на новое активити.

Comment: посмотри тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352132/getimageresource-android-is-this-possible